# What causes AbstractMethodError for scala implicit val?

Tags: scala, dependency-management, implicit, abstractmethoderror

I have a `gears` library, depending on

```
"org.typelevel"              %% "cats-core"        % "2.7.0",
"org.typelevel"              %% "cats-effect"      % "2.5.4"
```

cats-effect 2.5.4 depends on cats-core 2.6.1, so the latter is evicted. I'm not sure this matters though.

This library is used by a few services. In the `gears` library there is StreamMetrics trait used by main (runnable) class of all of them. It contains following piece of code:

```
implicit val traverseMeasured: Traverse[Measured] = new Traverse[Measured] { ... }
```

In some (but not all) services I get following error when I try to start them (I added newlines):

```
java.lang.AbstractMethodError: Receiver class my.company.platform.image.MainModule$$anon$9
does not define or inherit an implementation of the resolved method 
'abstract void my$company$gear$metrics$StreamMetrics$_setter_$traverseMeasured_$eq(cats.Traverse)' 
of interface my.company.gear.metrics.StreamMetrics.
```

From my understanding the `my$company$gear$metrics$StreamMetrics$_setter_$traverseMeasured_$eq(cats.Traverse)` is setter generated by scala compiler for `implicit val traverseMeasured`. This setter is defined and obviously used only in `StreamMetrics` trait - it's `val` so I can't set it anywhere else. So why the error?

Comment: The cause of it is version mismatch. How to fix it? Get rid of the version conflict.

Comment: But how it works? And why the "gears" library compiles? And what difference between versions can cause such error? It's Scala compiler that creates the setter method isn't it? So why it depends on cats version?